# xcode includes of header files

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, plugins

I am trying to compile a sample project for a browser plugin (http://pushingtheweb.com/2010/06/boilerplate-for-a-npapi-plugin/) using xcode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard.

I have never used xcode before.

When I try to build I get an error with an include (AE/AERegistry.h: No such file or directory)

When I click on the file it takes me to the header file AE.h (which is in folder /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/Headers) and has the lines:

```
ifndef __AEREGISTRY__
include <AE/AERegistry.h>
endif
```

Firstly I dont know how to find out why AE.h is included in the build as I cant see it "included" anywhere.

Secondly why cant it find AERegistry.h which is in four separate locations on the computer?
I manually added one of the folders to the Header paths but it made no difference.

Why is it AE/AEReistry when it is not in a folder AE?

Thanks for any help
George

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go into the build settings, find "compiler flags"(CFLAGS), and add something like:

```
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

And then do:

```
#include <AERegistry.h>
```

Comment: I tried that.. no joy.
I added the path in the "Other C Flags" setting